# In an MPI task, how do I find out the number of processors available to each node?

Tags: c++, mpi, distributed-computing

So I run an open MPI C++ program. (Instances of) the same program get's spawned on multiple nodes.

Now the number of cores actually assigned/available to these instances varies. Some instances get assigned an entire node (with 24 cores), but some instances only get assigned one core. If the program has multiple hardware threads available, then it uses custom threading to make use of those hardware threads.

(Sometimes the slurm scheduler schedules some of the instances on nodes that are also assigned to instances of other programs, hence not all cores are available to the node.)

In c++ i can request the number of hardware threads on the node as

```
std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
```

But this (seems to) give me the total number of hardware threads on the node (always 24 in my case). I am interested in knowing the number of threads assigned/available to this MPI program. (Perhaps there is no such concept; I am not very experienced in MPI and cluster computing. If so, then I am interested in figuring out in some other way whether the instance of my C++ program is run on a node that is currently also hosting other programs/computing tasks.)

Comment: you typically ask slurm a given number of MPI tasks, with a given number of cores per MPI task. So the number of threads a MPI task should use is exactly what you asked slurm for.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there any way to verify that slurm gave the number of threads as requested? Looking at results, it seems I don't always get what was requested..